# Downloading JQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/node/7411

It seems like it's not available for download any more. Is there alternative way to download jquery plugins?

Comment: How are we supposed to know what plugin you want.

Comment: You should at least include the name of the plugin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the jQuery team finishes rebuilding the plugins repository, it may be available again.  Until then, you'll just have to google the name and see what you come up with.  The owner may have their own site.

Here are a couple possibilities:

https://github.com/peol/jquery-text-selection-special-event

http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-text-change-custom-event

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to find out what the file name is, cant find much by googleing the name of plugin alone. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll use first one.